# should I delete my question because the answer turned out to be too specific?

Tags: discussion

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/what-is-in-a-d

I thought this was something used in Japanese, but it seems it is terminology used in electronics.  Now should i delete my question because the answer reveals that the question was about somethign that probably won't help other people or leave it because when i made i thought it was a valid japanese question?

This can also apply going forward, when answers reveal that the question was too localized.

Comment: As I understand it, the reason the question was closed is not because it is too specific, but because it turned out to have nothing to do with Japanese.

Comment: Since it seems everybody (@Mark included) agreed it wasn't really relevant to JLU and it had been closed with only an embryo of answer, I took the liberty to delete it. My thinking is that: 1. the closed stem of a question does not really serve any purpose to anybody 2. its bizarre wording and [closed] status might put off *some* new users 3. since everybody agrees, all votes given/taken should be reset (which 'delete' does). I hope that's OK with everybody, I'll be happy to undelete if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, in this case I have to disagree with Axioplase. While we are indeed in beta and activity is good, activity for activity's sake alone is not. Keeping the question around pollutes the pool of questions on the site, which are generally meant to be helpful and/or interesting to the people reading them. As this is a site which is about the Japanese language, I am of the opinion that this particular should probably be deleted -- as it is not really about Japanese at all.

Of course, I don't think this does or should reflect poorly on Mark, either. This is a mistake that anybody could make.

It's also worth noting again that the question was closed for being **off topic** rather than **too localized**...

Answer (score 2):

Well, it has been answered anyway, and, for the moment, it makes activity on the site (which is still in beta). So, let's keep it; you didn't know it was too localised (even though a quick google may have told you that it was).

Comment: You would likely have to double check, but I don't believe that they use closed or deleted questions towards the site activity metrics.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the metrics, but about the feeling one might have when reading the site.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you *have to* delete it.  It has already been closed as off topic, and it will not float up on the list of questions unless the question or the answer is edited.  It seems to me that whether you delete it or not makes little difference.

If you *want to* delete it, that is also fine, but I do not know if an asker can delete a question after it was answered and closed.

Comment: yeah after amanda closed it i still had the ability to delete it.

Comment: @Mark: I think that you can only cast a vote to delete after the question is closed.  The question page shows that it was deleted by a moderator (Dave).  I guess that he deleted the question after noticing your delete vote.

Comment: i never actually deleted it.  Dave beat me to the punch.  But the option was there.  Not sure if it was a deletion or a vote.  Being my own post, I just figured it would be out right deletable